# What is the keycode of the arrow keys in the Numeric keypad?

Tags: flex4

I would like to use numeric keypad arrow keys for accessing my mp3 player but I don't find the key codes. I was wondering if the key code exists for those keys.

Serenity.

Comment: The answer by Neeraj is correct, unless you mean something else?

Comment: I mean the number keypad key codes. I managed to search them from the following website http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=654089

Comment: Sorry but you clearly wrote **arrow** keys - one could never tell you meant the numbers themselves..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
37  LEFT ARROW key
38  UP ARROW key
39  RIGHT ARROW key
40  DOWN ARROW key
```